# Run a For Loop with Subset of Data with new Range of Dates every Loop

Tags: r, for-loop, tidyr

So I have a set of dates and corresponding values that I want to run through a for loop. The challenge is I want to define a new set of dates every time the for loop runs. This is to test for leading and lagging variables. Let's say the data looks like this:

```
Date       Y      X
2000 Q1    100    1.5
2000 Q2    50     2
2000 Q3    75     -1
2000 Q4    25     0
2001 Q1    0      3
2001 Q2    1000   4 
2001 Q3    40     1
2001 Q4    80     2
2002 Q1    0      0
2002 Q2    0      1
2002 Q3    500    1
2002 Q4    0      0
```

Now how can I write a for loop that will select a new range of dates every time so I can regress Y vs X? What I imagine this would look like is:

```
for(i in (range of dates)){
    test <- data %>% filter(Date > min(range of dates) &
                            Date < max(range of dates)
    lm(Y~X, test)}
```

And the data samples chosen by the for loop would look like this:

```
Date       Y      X
2000 Q1    100    1.5
2000 Q2    50     2
2000 Q3    75     -1
2000 Q4    25     0
2001 Q1    0      3
2001 Q2    1000   4 
2001 Q3    40     1
```

Next iteration:

```
Date       Y      X
2001 Q1    0      3
2001 Q2    1000   4 
2001 Q3    40     1
2001 Q4    80     2
2002 Q1    0      0
2002 Q2    0      1
2002 Q3    500    1
2002 Q4    0      0
```

So it leaves out the first year and select a new year to go on the end of the sample every time the for loop runs.

Comment: So you only want to choose a year and use all four quarters of that year in the min/max? What type is `Date` defined as?

Comment: I want to choose a new range of years every time the loop runs and leave out the first year on the new sample every time it executes again. First time: 2000, 2001. Next Time, 2001, 2002 (Leave out 2000 and add 2002). Date is a character variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> library(tidyverse)
> df <- data.frame(
    Date = c(
      paste0('2000 Q', 1:4),
      paste0('2001 Q', 1:4),
      paste0('2002 Q', 1:4)
    ),
    Y = c(
      100, 50, 75, 25,
      0, 1000, 40, 80,
      0, 0, 500, 0
    ),
    X = c(
      1.5, 2, -1, 0,
      3, 4, 1, 2,
      0, 1, 1, 0
    ),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )

> df
      Date    Y    X
1  2000 Q1  100  1.5
2  2000 Q2   50  2.0
3  2000 Q3   75 -1.0
4  2000 Q4   25  0.0
5  2001 Q1    0  3.0
6  2001 Q2 1000  4.0
7  2001 Q3   40  1.0
8  2001 Q4   80  2.0
9  2002 Q1    0  0.0
10 2002 Q2    0  1.0
11 2002 Q3  500  1.0
12 2002 Q4    0  0.0

> year_range <- df %>% transmute(
    years = str_sub(
      Date, start = 1L, end = 4L
    )
  ) %>% unique() %>% pull() # Extract unique years

> for (cur_year in 1:(length(year_range) - 1)) {

    test <- df %>% filter(
      str_sub(
        Date, start = 1L, end = 4L
      ) %in% c(
        year_range[cur_year],
        year_range[cur_year + 1]
      )
    )

    print(
      lm(
        formula = Y ~ X, 
        data = test
      )
    )

  }
```

The output printed from the above `lm`s that cover the years `2000`-`2001` and then `2001`-`2002` are

```
Call:
lm(formula = Y ~ X, data = test)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            X  
     -25.78       126.10  


Call:
lm(formula = Y ~ X, data = test)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            X  
     -40.71       162.14
```